# Regular Expression to validate price

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that validate price in the format like:
**0.07 //valid

0.0 //Invalid

20 //valid**

All the above Expressions are that which I want to achieve

```
^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

I use the above Expression which also accepts 0.0 which is invalid in my case.
Thank you.

Comment: c# or javascript? In c#, you would just use `decimal.TryParse`

Comment: `{1,4}` detects 1 to 4 digits, so just change that to `{2,4}`

Comment: what is the language and framework you are using? javascript or c#?

Comment: @smn.tino I use c#

Comment: is there any specific reason why you are using regex for solving this issue? is your price value a string value?

Comment: @Slai I want that after decimal no 0 will be accepted unless there should be a digit above than 0 like,0.0000 not accepted but 0.00007 should be accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts that what follows from the start of the line is not zero or times a zero followed by an optional part that matches a dot and only zeroes.

[`^(?!0*\.0+$)\d*(?:\.\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/bhicQ2/2)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `0*\.0+$` Match zero or more times a 0 followed by a dot and one or more times a 0 until the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\d*` Match zero or more times a digit
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.\d+` Match a dot followed by one or more digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` Assert the end of the line

Comment: your answer worked but It does not accept 5.00 or 4.00 or any format like this.

Comment: @Joojoo I have updated my answer. Do you exactly want to match `\d{0,8}` and `\d{1,4}`? Should it also match `0` or `0000`?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use that RegEx, but then also check for `value > 0`
I presume you also don't want a negative price - which other 'number checking' methods will most likely consider valid

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I would advice to use standard libraries to validate decimal values, like using [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx).

You may then implement something like:

```
public static bool IsValid(string price) {

    var result = Decimal.TryParse(price, out decimal d);

    if (result && d != 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```